# cache_wsdl constant meanings

Tags: php, soap

I'm working on some code that makes SOAP calls to a web service. While making changes on the server side of things, I needed to refresh the WSDL very frequently, so I was using `'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE` in my options for the constructor. Changes on the server side have settled down and I now want to cache the WSDL. I did some quick timing on single requests to see if there was any performance increase and didn't really see any. I understand `WSDL_CACHE_DISK` will save a copy of the wsdl in my /tmp directory, which saves on a request, and makes sense to me. **But I'm not sure how `WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY` or `WSDL_CACHE_BOTH` changes behavior?** Does `wsdl_cache_memory` store the xml or parsed wsdl in memory... between requests... for a day? How does this differ between CLI and Web? I can not find any documentation on how these flags actually affect behavior.

Comment: Also interested.. it's VERY vague... What is the default setting? How long does it cache it? Can the time it is cached be changed? Or is it detecting changes automatically and giving the new one when needed?

Comment: I think the answer lies here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/b925f2a7ec615b2c6fbf1fa54d24affa5c187acd/ext/soap/php_sdl.c#L3075

Answer (score 0):

Further research.. Try setting these in php.ini

```
soap.wsdl_cache_dir [/temp] # make sure this folder is writeable by php (if using disk cache)
    # otherwise give the web server access to it
    # check what webserver has for user for example _www or www-data
    # Example on MAC:
    # chown -R $(whoami):_www /temp 

soap.wsdl_cache_ttl [seconds] # Time To Live, how long it is cached
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/soap.configuration.php

Comment: Thanks Ozzie, but I was looking for a explanation of how setting the cache option to wsdl_cache_memory or wsdl_cache_both differ from wsdl_cache_disk